# TFS Build variable current sprint TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have a CI build server doing automated builds and would like to include the current sprint/iteration number in the assembly version. Is there an environment variable or easy way of getting the current sprint number in the build processes? TFS On Permise 2015 Update 3

Answer (score 8):

There isn’t build-in variable to get current sprint, but you can use REST API.
Steps:

1. Add a PowerShell file to the source control (e.g. included in your project and check in)

Code:

```
Param(
   [string]$collection,
   [string]$projectName,
   [string]$token
)
$uri="$collection/$projectName/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?`$timeframe=current&api-version=v2.0-preview"
Write-Output $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $token)}

Write-Output "success"
Write-Output $result.value.path

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=currentSprint;]$($result.value.path)"
```

2. Edit your build definition
3. Click Options tab and check Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token

[image]

4. Add PowerShell build step and specify PowerShell file (step 1) (arguments: -collection $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) -projectName $(System.TeamProject) -token $(System.AccessToken) )

[image]

After that, the current sprint value is stored in currentSprint variable.

Comment: Any chance we could get as intrinsic variable so I can make the build number include the sprint name - at the moment I have to update a variable every iteration to keep them in step